# JavaScript closure and the this object

Tags: javascript, object, closures, this

I thought I had a reasonable understanding of the `this` object in JavaScript. When dealing with objects, callbacks, and both events and handlers, I haven't had a problem with it since time immemorial. Now, however, all has changed.

I've fallen head over heels in love with JavaScript. Pure JS, that is, not jQuery, prototype.js, dojo... So naturally, I've taken to using closures. In some cases, though, `this` is catching me off guard here. Take this snippet for one:

```
function anyFunc(par)
{
    //console.log(par);
    console.log(this);
}

function makeClosure(func)
{
    return function(par)
    {
        return func(par);
    }
}
var close = makeClosure(anyFunc);
close('Foo');

var objWithClosure = {cls:makeClosure(anyFunc),prop:'foobar'};
objWithClosure.cls(objWithClosure.prop);

var scndObj = {prop:'Foobar2'};
scndObj.cls = makeClosure;
scndObj.cls = scndObj.cls(anyFunc);
scndObj.cls(scndObj.prop);
```

In all three cases, `this` logs as the window object. It's an easy fix, of course:

```
function makeClosure(func)
{
    return function(par)
    {
        return func.call(this,par);
    }
}
```

*This fix works, I put it here to avoid people answering this, without explaining what I need to know: why is this behaving the way it does here?*

ensures the caller is effectively the object that the closure belongs to. What I fail to understand is this:
Sure enough, `this` points to the window object in the first case, but in other cases, it shouldn't. I tried logging `this` in the makeClosure function just before returning, and it did log the object itself, not the `window` object. But when the actual closure is used, `this` is back to pointing to the window object. Why?

The only thing I can think of is that, by passing the `anyFunc` function as an argument, I'm actually passing `window.anyFunc`. So I tried this quick fix:

```
function makeClosure(func)
{
    var theFunc = func;
    return function(par)
    {
        theFunc(par);
    }
}
```

With the expected results, `this` now points to the objects, but again: Why? I have a few idea's (`theFunc` is a reference to the function in the local scope [`this > private: theFunc`]?), but I'm sure there are people here with a lot more know-how when it comes to JS, so I was hoping to get some more explanation or links to articles worth reading from them...

Thanks

**Update**

[Here's a fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/3chdp/), may be I left something out, but here this logs all sorts of things ;)

**Edit/Update 2**

[The case that confuses me](http://jsfiddle.net/7Skbc/1/) is here.

**Final Edit**

Ok, This is getting a rather messy post. So to clarify: What I was expecting was a behaviour similar to this:

```
function makeClosure()
{
    function fromThisFunc()
    {
        console.log(this);
    }
    return fromThisFunc;
}

var windowContext = makeClosure();
windowContext();
var objectContext = {cls:makeClosure()};
objectContext.cls();
```

What caught me, was that the function `anyFunc` wasn't declared within the correct scope, and therefore, `this` pointed to the window object. I found this out by reading an [ancient scroll](http://jibbering.com/faq/notes/closures/#clEncap) I found somewhere on the web.

> But something a little more complicated has happened because the function object now referred to by globalVar was created with a [[scope]] property referring to a scope chain containing the Activation/Variable object belonging to the execution context in which it was created (and the global object). Now the Activation/Variable object cannot be garbage collected either as the execution of the function object referred to by globalVar will need to add the whole scope chain from its [[scope]] property to the scope of the execution context created for each call to it.

So what I needed to do, was simplify rather then complicate things:

```
function fromThisFunc()
{
    console.log(this);
}

function makeClosure(funcRef)
{
    //some code here
    return funcRef;
}
```

That should work, right?

PS: I'll except Alnitak's answer, but special thanks goes to Felix Kling for all the patience and info.

Comment: I don't really get what other answer than a link to a global explanation of closures could be made. This course is an excellent reading and should remove all uncertainties :  http://ejohn.org/apps/learn/

Comment: The problem isn't that I don't get closures. What is causing the headaches is that I'm not entirely sure what happens to the `this` object when making closures the way I do here

Comment: I cannot reproduce the behviour you describe. I get `DOMWindow`, `Object`, `Object`: http://jsfiddle.net/GErkX/, whereas your second "fix" gives me 3 x `DOMWindow`: http://jsfiddle.net/tZXQF/

Comment: Which is the correct behaviout btw, so I would be really surprised if it would work like you described.

Comment: Re your second edit: What is confusing here? You are calling `func` like a normal function (`func(par)`) hence inside the function `this` refers to `window`. This is your first case which seems to be what you expected.

Comment: @FelixKling: `this` refers to the object in the `makeClosure` function, and returns a function to an object, that returns the return value of the function `anyFunc`, which is called from the `cls` method. Somehow I expect the calling context to be the object, since the function is called from a method

Comment: @EliasVanOotegem: I'm totally confused now :D But whenever you have a function call like `foo()`, inside that function `this` refers to `window`, no matter where it was called from. If you have `obj.foo()` then `this` refers to `obj`. You should have a look at https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/this. You can explicitly override `this` with `.call()` and `.apply()` (like you did).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As soon as you call:

```
return func(par);
```

You're creating a new scope (with its own `this`) and in this case because you haven't specified an object, `this === window` usually or *undefined* in strict mode.  The called function **does not** inherit whatever `this` was in the calling scope.

Ways to set a value for *this* are:

```
myobj.func(par);  // this === myobj
```

or

```
func.call(myobj, ...)  // this === myobj
```

There are also:

- [*apply*](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/6.0/index.html#sec-function.prototype.apply)
- [*bind*](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/6.0/index.html#sec-function.prototype.bind)
- [*arrow functions*](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/6.0/index.html#sec-arrow-function-definitions), where *this* is set to the same value as the outer execution context (also see [*MDN:Arrow functions*](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/Arrow_functions) )

Comment: or -apparently- create a local var in the `makeClosure` function, and assign the func parameter to that variable... also, `return func(par)` is the function body, of a function that is returned to an object, so I assumed the call to `func(par)` would be made in the object's context. Why isn't it?

Comment: @EliasVanOotegem I'm still trying to get my head around that former case...  I can't replicate it locally.

Comment: @EliasVanOotegem: I think your tests are flawed somehow, especially the last one. Whenever you make a simply function call `foo()`, `this` will refer to the global object, no matter where the function was defined. In which environment  are you testing the code? Creating a local variable does not make a difference in this case. The parameter is local as well. Your first fix works fine here: http://jsfiddle.net/GErkX/

Comment: @FelixKling I can't replicate that case either (under Chrome 18)

Comment: @FelixKling: I am testing in Chrome, and I have provided a fiddle with the exact (messy) code. The first fix does work, but I want to know _why_ `this` is what I need it to be at one time, and the window object the other

Comment: @EliasVanOotegem: So I got the description of your problem wrong? It sounded like you still got 3 times the `window` object with the `.call()` fix: *" I tried logging this in the makeClosure function just before returning, and it did log the object itself, not the window object. But when the actual closure is used, this is back to pointing to the window object."* Which is not the case. It logs the object. And since you expected that it seems you understood how everything works. Or not? I definitely recommend to read https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/this.

Comment: @EliasVanOotegem a fiddle showing _just_ the case that's confusing you would be more helpful.

Comment: @RobG I disagree with some of your edit - `.bind` is just a wrapper around `.call`, and an arrow function explicitly _doesn't_ set `this` - it just leaves it with the value that was in the outer scope.

Answer (score 1):

The value of `this` depends only on whether you call the function as a method or as a function.

If you call it as a method, `this` will be the object that the method belongs to:

```
obj.myFunction();
```

If you call it as a function, `this` will be the `window` object:

```
myFunction();
```

Note that even if you are in a method that belongs to an object, you still have to call other methods in the object using the method syntax, otherwise they will be called as functions:

```
this.myOtherFunction();
```

If you put a method reference in a variable, you will detach it from the object, and it will be called as a function:

```
var f = obj.myFunction;
f();
```

The [`call`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/call) and [`apply`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/apply) methods are used to call a function as a method even if it's not a method in the object (or if it's a method in a different object):

```
myFunction.call(obj);
```

Comment: thanks, but not really an answer to this question... I currently use `call`, but I want to know _why_ JS behaves the way it does. on the method reference bit: it is well odd that, when I create a function reference (not method, a function) in a function that is attached to an object, that very function ref will be called as a method

Comment: @EliasVanOotegem it's because as soon as you _attach_ that function reference to an object, it becomes a method of that object.  It's the opposite to what happens when you _detach_ a method.

Comment: but I'm not attaching that function directly, I'm attaching `makeClosure`, and passing a function reference to it. Within `makeClosure`, that passed reference is assigned to a variable. When I use that variable, the function (passed as argument) is called as a method, but when I use the argument directly, it's called as a function... that is the confusing part

Comment: @EliasVanOotegem: No it does not: http://jsfiddle.net/tZXQF/ If  you are referring to http://jsfiddle.net/3chdp/, then note that you are still using `.call()`. It has nothing to do with the local variable, if you remove it you get the same result.

Comment: @FelixKling: you're right, sorry... got a bit confused by excessively logging `this`

Comment: @EliasVanOotegem: No worries :) So... is everything clear or is there still something you would like to know in this regard?