# Javascript: Create a sub-class within a class

Tags: javascript, class, scope

I know Javascript doesn't support classes, so I'm creating a `Cube` object, then declaring its prototype methods. Within `Cube`, I want to create a `flip` object with more methods within it:

```
// Create Cube class
var Cube = function(){
    this.x = 0;
    this.y = 0;
    //...
}

// Add methods to Cube prototype
Cube.prototype = {
    initialize: function(){
        //...
    },

    // Adding sub-functions within flip
    flip: {
        start: function(){
            console.log(this.x); // This.x is undefined!
        },

        end: function(){
            console.log("Ending flip");
        }
    },

    getPos: function(){
        console.log(this.x); // Correctly outputs 0
    }

// Declare instance of Cube
var cubeInstance = new Cube();
cubeInstance.flip.start();
```

However, I'm getting the wrong scope for `this` within `flip.start()`, because it outputs the `flip` object, instead of the `Cube` object I want:

```
Object { start: Cube.prototype.flip.start(), end: Cube.prototype.flip.end() }
```

What do you suggest I do so that `cubeInstance.flip.start();` will trigger the `start()` method, but I can still access the `Cube` variables (namely, this.x and this.y)?

Comment: This should explain it pretty well: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10512087/javascript-closure-and-the-this-object

Comment: *this* has nothing to do with scope. It's always resolved within the current execution context (except for *bind* and [`=>` functions](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/Arrow_functions)).

Comment: you don't need a `flip` object. you just need two functions: `flip_start` and `flip_end`. done. there's a little devil wearing a Java T-shirt sitting on your shoulder telling you to make objects, make them everywhere, make them all day long -- 'objects are so good! OO is the one true way' it whispers in your ear. look right at him and say "_JavaScript is not Java!_" and then fillip him away. do this every time he shows up. eventually tranquility will be yours.